# How does mount points work in Fedora 36 and its file manager?

Tags: linux, fedora, mount

I upgraded my very old Debian to all-new Fedora 36, and I have some fundamental questions about the magic behind Fedora mount points (using Gnome, the default window manager and the Files app).

**The case:**

When I open the Files program I can see the "Computer" (the root filesystem) and my 2nd SSD (/dev/sdb1), called "SSD 2". When I click the "SSD 2" the program ask my password (with sudo provilege).

The partition is mounted on "/run/media/myuser/SSD 2" and all files and directories in "SSD 2" belongs to myuser:myuser.

**What I need to know:**

1. From where the file manager got the volume's name to show?
2. "/dev/sdb1" is mounted in "/run/media/myuser/SSD 2". Where is the configuration of that path? How to configure the file manager (or gnome, or fedora) to mount my "SSD 2" in another directory, like "/mnt/ssd2/" ?
3. What is the command or how to mount that SSD like the Files program does? `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /run/media/myuser/SSD\ 2/` (or another directory) works, but all the drive contents belongs to root:root, as expected.

My /etc/fstab has only 3 entries: /, /boot and /home.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the mounting done from GUI (not only in GNOME, but also other desktop environments like KDE or Xfce) is done by [UDisks](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/), a system daemon for storage management. In GNOME some part of the "magic" is also resposibility of [gvfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs).

> From where the file manager got the volume's name to show?

From the filesystem label. You can add a label to most filesystems (for example with `e2fslabel` for Ext4 or `ntfslabel` for NTFS), it's just a nice human readable identifier. If a filesystem has a label UDisks will use for the mount point, if it doesn't have one filesystem UUID will be used, so the mountpoint will look like `/run/media/<user>/0dd6e6c1-a451-4a72-bdbd-0538a60c2028` for example.

> "/dev/sdb1" is mounted in "/run/media/myuser/SSD 2". Where is the configuration of that path?

That is default the location for temporary mount points hardcoded in UDisks.

> How to configure the file manager (or gnome, or fedora) to mount my "SSD 2" in another directory, like "/mnt/ssd2/" ?

If you want a different mount point, you need to put the device in [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fstab), UDisks will honor the mount point and mount options from there. You can use the `noauto` mount option if you don't want the device to be mounted automatically during boot and `nofail` can be also useful if you don't have the disk attached all the time. (You can manage fstab from GUI with GNOME Disks.)

> What is the command or how to mount that SSD like the Files program does

UDisks has a commanline tool called `udisksctl` so to mount you a device you can use

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
```

and to unmount it later

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1
```

> but all the drive contents belongs to root:root, as expected

I guess this a NTFS file system so in this case your `mount` command is missing the `uid=` and `gid=` mount options that tell the system who should own the files, UDisks does this by default.